How can I make a custom loss function in tensorflow, which takes inputs of model, predictions of model, and weights of model as it's parameters
I am trying to make a model which solves a partial differential equation (PDE). The problem is, it requires a make loss function which takes as its parameters:

Inputs given to model
Predictions of model
Weights of model
predictions for a different input but same weights that model has dring a batch.

For example: if model has two input nodes lets call first 'x' and second 't', for a batch has 3 instances let's say [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)], loss function requires predictions for these input values and it also requires preditions for input values [(1,0),(3,0),(5,0)], here second neuron will have all zero inputs. This is required for solving the PDE as it requires N(x,t) and N(x,0) where 'N' represents neural network and 'x' and 't' represent two input nodes.
This needs to be done for every batch.

How can I do this?
# model
model=keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(2,activation='sigmoid'),
    keras.layers.Dense(5,activation='sigmoid'),
    keras.layers.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')
])

# inputs for neural net
x=np.random.uniform(1,5,10)
t=np.random.uniform(1,5,10)
inputs=np.stack((x,t),axis=1)
inputs=tf.convert_to_tensor(inputs)


# function for calculting z1*x and z2*t +b where z1 and z2 are weights for x and t respectively
def P(input_values,weight_of_x,weight_of_t,bias):
    
    input_of_x=input_values[0]
    
    input_of_t=input_values[1]
    
    p_i=(weight_of_x*input_of_x)+(weight_of_t*input_of_t) + bias

    return p_i
    
# calculates output for sigmoid function
def sigmoid(p):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-1*(p)))

# derivative of output with respect to inputs of t (2nd input neuron)
def dN_by_dt(input_value,weights_of_l1,weights_of_l2):
    
    w_connected_to_x=weights_of_l1[0][0]
    w_connected_to_t=weights_of_l1[0][1]
    b_l1=weights_of_l1[1]
    
    w_l2=weights_of_l2[0]
    b_l2=weights_of_l2[1]
    
    temp=[]

    for i in range(len(weights_of_l2)):
        
        p_i=P(input_value,w_connected_to_x[i],w_connected_to_t[i],b_l1[i])
        
        activation=sigmoid(p_i)
        
        temp2=w_l2[i]*(1-activation)*activation*w_connected_to_t[i]

        temp.append(temp2)
        
    return sum(temp)

# double derivative of output w.r.t inputs od x (1st input neuron)
def d2N_by_dx2(input_value,weights_of_l1,weights_of_l2):
    
    w_connected_to_x=weights_of_l1[0][0]
    w_connected_to_t=weights_of_l1[0][1]
    b_l1=weights_of_l1[1]
    
    w_l2=weights_of_l2[0]
    b_l2=weights_of_l2[1]
    
    temp=[]
    
    for i in range(len(weights_of_l2)):
        
        p_i=P(input_value,w_connected_to_x[i],w_connected_to_t[i],b_l1[i])
        
        activation=sigmoid(p_i)
        
        d_sig_by_dp_i = activation*(1-activation)
        
        temp2=w_l2[i]*w_connected_to_x[i]*( ( d_sig_by_dp_i * w_connected_to_x[i] ) - ( 2 * activation * d_sig_by_dp_i * w_connected_to_x[i] ) )
        
        temp.append(temp2)
        
        
    return sum(temp)
        
    
# final cost function
def cost_function(input_vals,pred1,pred2,weights_of_l1,weights_of_l2):  #pred are normal predictions and pred2 are predictions with t=0

    dN_dt=np.array([])
    
    d2N_dx2=np.array([])

    for i in range(len(input_vals)): 
        
        temp1= dN_by_dt(input_vals[i],weights_of_l1,weights_of_l2)
        dN_dt=np.append(dN_dt,temp1)

        temp2= d2N_by_dx2(input_vals[i],weights_of_l1,weights_of_l2)
        d2N_dx2=np.append(d2N_dx2,temp2)
    
    e1=np.array([])
    e2=np.array([])
    
    for i in range(len(dN_dt)):
        temp1= np.array(( dN_dt[i] - d2N_dx2[i] -( pred1[i] * (1 - pred1[i]) * (pred1[i] - 1) ) )**2)
        e1=np.append(e1,temp1)
        
        x_i= input_vals[i][0]
        
        temp2= np.array(( pred2[i] - ( 0.5 * ( 1 + np.tanh( x_i / ( 2*(2**0.5) ) ) ) ) )**2)
        e2=np.append(e2,temp2)
        
        
    E = tf.convert_to_tensor(e1 + e2)
    return E
    
    
optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()

batch_size=5
for epoch in range(3):
    for i in range(0,len(inputs),batch_size):
        x_batch=inputs[i: (i+batch_size)]
        
        with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
            tape.watch(x_batch)
            pred1=model(x_batch)
            
#             inputs were all inputs of t are zero
            temp_batch=x_batch
            x_vals=np.array(temp_batch[:,0])
            all_0=np.zeros(len(x_vals))
            temp_batch2=np.stack((x_vals,all_0),axis=1)
#             getting prediction for the above input
            pred2=model(temp_batch2)
            
            weights_of_l1=model.layers[1].get_weights()
            weights_of_l2=model.layers[2].get_weights()
            
            cost=cost_function(x_batch,pred1,pred2,weights_of_l1,weights_of_l2)

            
        gradients = tape.gradient(cost, model.trainable_variables)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))

It's giving the following error:
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: (['dense_9/kernel:0', 'dense_9/bias:0', 'dense_10/kernel:0', 'dense_10/bias:0', 'dense_11/kernel:0', 'dense_11/bias:0'],). Provided `grads_and_vars` is ((None, <tf.Variable 'dense_9/kernel:0' shape=(2, 2) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[-0.22757757, -1.1772537 ],
       [ 0.77507913,  0.11150062]], dtype=float32)>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_9/bias:0' shape=(2,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([0., 0.], dtype=float32)>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_10/kernel:0' shape=(2, 5) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 0.75440705, -0.41952217, -0.20862311, -0.5366657 ,  0.83467317],
       [-0.04175383, -0.8375001 ,  0.6257205 ,  0.20955968, -0.02585948]],
      dtype=float32)>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_10/bias:0' shape=(5,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_11/kernel:0' shape=(5, 1) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[-0.14150858],
       [-0.8269048 ],
       [-0.58234024],
       [-0.7746899 ],
       [-0.51618624]], dtype=float32)>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_11/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([0.], dtype=float32)>)).



You cannot use numpy in a loss function, it has to use tensorflow/keras functions in order for gradients to be computed at all.

Hi @Dr.Snoopy, could you explain further, how can I do it?

The error arises because your custom function mixes TensorFlow and NumPy operations. TensorFlow operations are essential for gradient calculation but you are using NumPy operations. So, to fix this error you need to replace all NumPy operations with their TensorFlow equivalents. This will enable the calculation of gradients for all operations involved. kindly refer to this gist.
